# itextsharp columntext overlapping with table

Tags: c#, itext

I have a columntext that comes before a pdftable, how do I stop the two elements from overlapping?

```
ColumnText addressHeader = new ColumnText(cb);
Phrase addressText = new Phrase("Lorem ipsum");
addressHeader.SetSimpleColumn(addressText, 34, 750, 580, 317, 15, Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
addressHeader.FollowingIndent = 10f;
addressHeader.Go();
PdfPTable contactTable = new PdfPTable(2);
float[] contactWidths = new float[] { 1f, 1f };
contactTable.TotalWidth = 400f;
contactTable.LockedWidth = true;
contactTable.SpacingBefore = 10f;
contactTable.SetWidths(contactWidths);
PdfPCell contactInfoCell = new PdfPCell();
contactInfoCell.AddElement(new Chunk("Date Requested));
doc.Add(contactTable);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn()` is used to absolutely position things whereas the `Document.Add()` method is used to relatively position things. Absolute and relative objects aren't aware of each other, that's just their nature.

So if you can use relative positioning then get rid of the `ColumnText` and add the `Phrase` to the document normally.

If you need absolute positioning then you'll need to absolutely position the table as well. This can be done using the table's `WriteSelectedRows()` method where you tell how many rows to write and what's the upper left corner to start drawing at.

A third possible option is that if you're using the `ColumnText.SetSimpleColumn()` to draw a page header then you can just change the document's margins. You can still absolutely position things outside of the margins but when you use `Document.Add()` it will respect those margins.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I went with the first option but the other two could also be used.